# How to communicate from main app to client app C#

Tags: c#, com, pipeline

I've looked everywhere to find some help with this question but it's all for communicating with web clients or from web clients.

I want a main app running from a "server" and the client app running from desktops on a network. I want the main app to be able to call functions in the client apps. These client apps are used to gather info and send back to the main app. What would be the best way, and the most "cost" effective to achieve this?

I've read a bit about pipelines, but not sure if this can be used?

Thank you.

Comment: WCF, ASP.NET MVC Web Api, Sockets, etc.

Comment: Two tin cans with a piece of string?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using just using a socket, WCF or msmq (message queue).  I am often faced with problems like this when configuring windows services - how can the desktop application communicate with the service.  I am currently using the message queue for inter-application communication in a number of cases and I have found it to be relatively simple and effective.  It is often overlooked for jobs like this.

Answer (score 0):

To call the client from the server app you can try [ASP.NET SignalR](http://signalr.net/).
Using signalR you can leverage [Hub APIs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api) to have a connection between your client and server.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple bidirectional comunication problem. I've solved it with WCF in these steps:

- Create a main application server with one exposed WCF server endpoint than may accept some usefull info as "client ip", "client web address"
- Create a client application than host a WCF server endpoint than may accept the server feedback comunication
- So when the client application start, it must call main application server sending the client endpoint address
- The main application server store the client informations e keep it for future use
- When the main application server need to send something to client(s) find information in stored information and try to call client directly.

It' more complex to describe than to write in c#

(you can do all og theese with websockets, but i've never tryed)

Comment: Thank you very much!! No idea why I haven't received any mail notifications of the replies here, but anyway. There any links for WCF that can point me in the right direction?  Thanx!!

Comment: i thing you can start here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms756474(v=vs.90).aspx